# How to use 'In' SQL keyword in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This is my SQL command

```
SELECT KEY,NAME
from  COMPANY c 
WHERE     KEY IN (select KEY from USER_COMPANY  where UserId = @UserId)
order by NAME asc
```

So I want to convert it to Entity Framework.

I try like this

```
 var userCompany = (from u in db.USER_COMPANY
                         where u.UserId == UserId 
                         select(u.KEY));

            var user = (from c in db.COMPANY
                        where (c => userCompany.Contains(c.KEY)
                        select c);
```

but it is not working.

How to use the SQL `IN` keyword in Entity Framework?

Comment: This isn't much help, but I'm on my phone and can't check code. You want to look into the LET keyword.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = from c in db.COMPANY
            where (from u in db.USER_COMPANY
                   where u.UserId == UserId
                   select u.KEY).Contains(c.KEY)
            orderby c.NAME
            select c.KEY, c.NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this SQL query has the exact same meaning:

```
SELECT c.KEY, c.NAME
FROM COMPANY c
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT KEY FROM USER_COMPANY where UserId = @UserId) u
ON U.KEY = C.KEY
ORDER BY c.NAME asc
```

So you should be able to just do:

```
var userCompany = (from u in db.USER_COMPANY
                   where u.UserId == UserId 
                   select(u.KEY)).Distinct();

var result = from c in db.COMPANY
             join u in userCompany
             on c.KEY = u.KEY
             select new {c.KEY, c.NAME};
```

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that the translation from `.Contains()` to `IN` is only just being added to EF6.

According to this work item (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/245) and the release note: Improved performance of Enumerable.Contains in LINQ queries.

So look for it in EF6