# Selecting multiple from LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I use this little piece of code to get the IDs I need, and put them in an array

```
var userids = from a in db.Person
              select a.idlist;

string[] idarray = userids.FirstOrDefault().ToString().Split(';');
```

How can I use this array of ids to select the matching rows in another query like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetStuff()
{
    var Item = from a in db.Table
               where a.id == idarray[0]
               and where a.id == idarray[1]
               and where a.id == idarray[2]
               etc...
               select new
                   {
                       a.itemid,
                       a.Element
                   };

    return Json(Item, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435343/how-to-use-in-sql-keyword-in-entity-framework) help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var Item = from a in db.Table
           where idarray.Contains(a.id)
           select new
               {
                   a.itemid,
                   a.Element
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Item = from a in db.Table
           where idarray.Contains(a.id)
           select new
               {
                   a.itemid,
                   a.Element
               }.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to use [Extension Method Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) syntax? I is same Linq, but just has more code-like view:

```
var Item = db.Table.Where(x => x.Contains(a.id))
           .Select(x => new
               {
                   a.itemid,
                   a.Element
               }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I usually do.

Get the IDs you need:

```
var ids = something.Where(s => s.SomeCondition).Select(s => s.Id);
```

Now Lets get the data based on the Ids:

```
var response = anothertable.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id);
```

You then can make it a list, array, or whatever you want to do with it. It will go through all the records in `anothertable` and find the records where the `a.Id` matches any of the `ids`.