# How to find a List<Object> using Find method of entity framework passing Array as parameter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, find, entity-framework-6

I would like to know how to find a `List<Object>` using Find method of Entity Framework passing Array(`object[]`) as parameter?

I want to find all data by Primary Key.

I first fill a list with all PK that I will use as reference:

```
List<int> lCodigoServicos = new List<int>();
foreach (ServicosSelecionadosModelView servicoSelecionado in lServicos.FindAll(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.selecionado) && s.selecionado.ToLower() == "on" ))
         lCodigoServicos.Add(servicoSelecionado.servico.SerId);
```

After fill my list of PK, I try find all data by PK

```
var lServicosInformados = db.Servicos.Find(lCodigoServicos.ToArray());
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

```
The specified parameter type 'System.Int32[]' is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.
```

Please, share with us how to do it properly. Thanks.

**Solution**
as described below, the right solution is:

```
var lServicosInformados = db.Servicos.Where(x => lCodigoServicos.Contains(x.PKId));
```

Comment: it could be dublicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435343/how-to-use-in-sql-keyword-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a [`Contains` query](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx):

```
var lServicosInformados = db.Servicos.Where(x => lCodigoServicos.Contains(x.PKId));
```

This assumes `PKId` is the name of your primary id column (you didn't specify the name).

Comment: Thank you @BrokenGlass. I was trying to use Find method, but, object[] is used for multiple keys of an entity, not multiple PKs. My mistake.